# Parsing Verilog net concatenation in a MatchFirst

Tags: python, verilog, string-concatenation, pyparsing

I have a simple grammar which parses a verilog concatenation:

```
scalar = (Optional(Word(nums + "_") + "'" + oneOf("d h b")) + Word(nums + "_")).setName("Scalar")
operator = oneOf("+ - * /").setName("Operator")
identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums+"_").setName("Identifier")
expr = (scalar | identifier) + ZeroOrMore(operator + (scalar | identifier))
range = expr + ":" + expr
index = "[" + range + "]"
single_netref = (identifier + Optional(index)).setName("Single Net Reference")
single_netref.setDebug()
lbracket = Literal("{").setName("Left Bracket").setDebug()
rbracket = Literal("}").setName("Left Bracket").setDebug()
concat_netref = (lbracket + single_netref + ZeroOrMore( Suppress( "," ) + single_netref ) + rbracket).setName("Net Concatination Reference")
concat_netref.setDebug()
```

If I parse the string "{ LegacyStatus3gPreStageQ1 , LegacyData3gPreStageQ1 }" using the parseString method, it parses just fine; however, I want to match either a concatenation of net references or a single net reference. To do this, I have tried:

```
netref = MatchFirst(concat_netref, single_netref).setName("Net Reference").setDebug()
```

However, this (and using Or()) always skips the last rbracket, but says it successfully matched the netref.  This was my debug output:

```
Match Net Reference at loc 0(1,1)
Match Left Bracket at loc 0(1,1)
Matched Left Bracket -> ['{']
Match Single Net Reference at loc 1(1,2)
Matched Single Net Reference -> ['LegacyStatus3gPreStageQ1']
Match Single Net Reference at loc 28(1,29)
Matched Single Net Reference -> ['LegacyData3gPreStageQ1']
Matched Net Reference -> ['{', 'LegacyStatus3gPreStageQ1', 'LegacyData3gPreStageQ1']
```

Why does adding the MatchFirst() element cause the rbracket to be missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MatchFirst should be passed a list of expressions.

Change

```
netref = MatchFirst(concat_netref, single_netref).setName("Net Reference")
```

to

```
netref = MatchFirst([concat_netref, single_netref]).setName("Net Reference")
```

Comment: Wow, I missed that.  <face-plant>  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Another reason I encourage pyparsing users to write this as `(concat_netref | single_netref).setName("Net Reference")`.